# Firebase wriitng a "0" rather than the actual variable content

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm updating a value in my database under a field called message threads. Under that thread I want to store the keys of all the users and in that key I want their picture. From this I've constructed a loop containing the following:

```
                firebase.database().ref('users/' + userUID + '/messageThreads/' + newThreadID).update({
                    "date": currentDate.getTime(),
                    "lastMessage": "",
                    "read": false,
                    "isGroup": true
                });
                console.log(groupUID);
                firebase.database().ref('users/' + userUID + '/messageThreads/' + newThreadID + "/" + "userUID").update({
                        [groupUID]: [groupPic]
                });
```

For some reason, under the database instead of the value of groupUID, it puts a zero.

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: That's how the firebase console represents an array (the "0" is the array index).   If you don't want an array, use `groupUID: groupPic` (without the array brackets.)

Comment: This now displays groupUID: and then the proper url. but it is supposed to display the value of the variable groupUID, not the string groupUID itself. Any suggestions?

Comment: Ah, I missed that.  See below (answer's getting too long to include in a comment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "0" was the array index (because you were pushing in the array `[groupPic]` instead of a plain value. That's easy, just use `groupPic`.

The dynamic key name is a bit trickier: the easiest way  is to define the object ahead of time, before setting it in firebase:

```
var newVal = {};
newVal[groupUID] = groupPic;

firebase.database().ref('path/to/ref').update(newVal);
```

### Or:

So I learned something today! (Thanks!) And now I understand how you wound up unintentionally using an array in the first place.

The shorthand notation you were using for the key was just fine, I'd just never seen it before.  So this would work too, it's equivalent to the above (if potentially a bit more confusing to read, because it *looks* like it's going to be an array):

```
firebase.database().ref('path/to/ref').update({[groupUID]: groupPic});
```

Comment: Much appreciated. This will help me a lot in the future.

Also, I had ended up searching some variation of "how do I insert variable content rather than variable name into Firebase" earlier to find that notation. Glad I could show you that!